# Dynamically turn subscription on and off to limit cache received "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

To limit the cache on the client side we thought we can turn the subscription to a specific Collection on and off by putting the Meteor.subscribe of that Collection in Meteor.render as suggested by the Meteor document - "In addition, calling Meteor.subscribe in a reactive context sets up a subscription which is automatically stopped when the context is invalidated."

However we keep getting the "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" error.

The flow of the program is the following:

```
Appliances = new Meteor.Collection 'appliances'
Alerts = new Meteor.Collection 'alerts'
```

On the client side

```
under Meteor.startup subscribes to collection 'appliances'
Meteor.subscribe ('appliances')
Use Appliances.find{}.observe to monitor changes
```

When a new Appliances item is detected, use Meteor.render to re-actively subscribe to alerts and list all alerts of the item

```
Meteor.render(function() {Meteor.subscribe(Alerts); .....}
```

Any idea what I did wrong? Suggestions?

Comment: Meteor document: "These Meteor functions run your code in a reactive context:
• Templates
• Meteor.render and Meteor.renderList
• Meteor.autorun
And the reactive data sources that can trigger changes are:
• Session variables
• Database queries on Collections
• Meteor.status
• The ready() method on a subscription handle
• Meteor.user
• Meteor.userId
• Meteor.loggingIn
In addition, calling Meteor.subscribe in a reactive context sets up a subscription which is automatically stopped when the context is invalidated"
It provides examples with Meteor.autorun, the one works with Meteor.subscribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no Idea where your Error message comes from. But You can archive the "only when necessary" subscription easily using `Deps.autorun()` and a Session variable:

anywhere on the client:

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
  if (!Session.get('isViewingAlerts')) Meteor.subscribe('alerts');
});
```

If you now use`Session.set('isViewingAlerts',false)`, the code in the autorun function is invalidated and gets re-executed.

Even further you could subscribe to a subset of alerts, by adding a parameter to the publish function 'alerts'.

EDIT:
I recently had the Problem, that a Template wasn't reactive when using dynamic subscriptions. As the subscription wasn't loaded on redraw. To solve the Problem we used a callback for Metor.subcribe that changes a Session variable to make the rendering of that Template dependent on the subscription to be ready and thereby gaining reactivity.

-best,
Jan

Comment: I did limit the volume of data sent the the client by modifying the server publish to limit the data retrieved. I used Meteor.render to auto refresh the web page when it's in view, I don't think Meteor.autorun can accomplish that. Instead of using Meteor.autorun to control my subscription I just manually subscribe and unsubscribe (use the stop() function of the subscription handle).

Comment: soo.. do you not use templates but your own render function to generate html? Meteor.autorun can establish as well, but cannot return html of course.

Comment: anyway, the render method shouldn't contain a subscribe call me thinks.

Comment: I do use templates with Meteor.render. I will need to look into how I can use Meteor.autorun. Does it make sense to call Meteor.autorun to do the dynamic subscription (when the tab is in session), then use Meteor.render to draw the alerts?

Comment: OK. I think I finally got it. It's probably true that I cannot use Meteor.subscribe under Meteor.render. I modified my code to use Meter.autorun as you suggested. From the doc it looks like the Session variable changed needs to be part of the Meteor.subscribe argument to triger the subscribe. BTW, it looks like Meteor.autorun has been changed to Deps.autorun in the latest version of Meteor. Thanks for the help!